# dependent select dropdown in struts using ajax

Tags: ajax, struts

I have three select boxes in my page named

```
country
state 
city
```

I want state to be show options based on country value and city based on state value.
How it would be achieved using ajax in struts.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

  <label>country</label>
  <select style="width:25%">
  <option value="volvo">India</option>
  <option value="saab">us</option>
   <option value="audi">uk</option>
    </select>
    <br>

     <label>state</label>
     <select style="width:25%">
     <option value="s"></option>
  <option value="r"></option>
 <option value="q"></option>
 <option value="p"></option>
</select>
<br>
<label>city</label>
 <select style="width:25%">
 <option value="a"></option>
 <option value="b"></option>
 <option value="c"></option>
<option value="d"></option>
</select>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Where's your JavaScript/jQuery code for achieving this? How will you fetch data from Struts based on the selected value of Country? Also note that you haven't given HTML elements a unique ID, it'll be hard to identify change on country and state select elements to update state and city accordingly.

Comment: actualy i d'nt have any idea about javascript and ajax.i want to populate state based on country and populate city based on state by using ajax and struts.so please send me source code.

Comment: I am sorry if this sounds rude but nobody has time to do your home work buddy. You'll have to come up with your own efforts first. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
                         **DropdownCountryAction.java**







   package p1;
   import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;
   import java.util.Map;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.HashMap;

   public class DropdownCountryAction {
   private Map<String,String>statemap=new HashMap<String,String>();
   private List<String>citylist=new ArrayList<String>();
   private String country;
   private String state;
   private String city;
public Map<String,String> getStatemap() {
    return statemap;
}
public void setStatemap(Map<String,String> statemap) {
    this.statemap = statemap;
}
public List<String> getCitylist() {
    return citylist;
}
public void setCitylist(List<String> citylist) {
    this.citylist = citylist;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;

}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}


public String execute(){
    if(country.equals("india")){

        statemap.put("1", "jharkhand");
        statemap.put("2", "bihar");
    }

    else if(country.equals("us")){
        statemap.put("3", "california");
        statemap.put("4", "texas");
    }
    return Action.SUCCESS;
}


public String cityexecute(){
    if(state.equals("2")){
        citylist.add("Sasaram");
        citylist.add("kudra");
    }
    else if(state.equals("1")){
        citylist.add("ranchi");
        citylist.add("bokaro");
    }

    else if(state.equals("3")){
        citylist.add("yuba city");
        citylist.add("beach city");
    }

    else if(state.equals("4")){
        citylist.add("cactus");
        citylist.add("calvert");
    }
    return Action.SUCCESS;

     }

     }



                                        **struts.xml**



           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
             <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration  2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
               <struts>
                 <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
                    <action name="countryAction" class="p1.DropdownCountryAction">
                 <result name="success">/state.jsp</result>
                        </action>


                  <action name="stateAction" class="p1.DropdownCountryAction"  method="cityexecute">
             <result name="success">/city.jsp</result>
               </action>
        </package>
          </struts>  

                                      ***index.jsp*** 



           <%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
               <%
                 String path = request.getContextPath();
               String basePath =      request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
           %>

               <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
            <html>
              <head>
   <base href="<%=basePath%>">

     <title>My JSP 'index.jsp' starting page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
      <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">    
        <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3">
        <meta http-equiv="description" content="This is my page">
         <!--
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
              -->
         </head>
           <script>
            function onCountryChange(str)
           {
             var xmlhttp;
             if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
             {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                 alert(str);
           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
               }
               else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
           }
             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
            document.getElementById("conid").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
              }
                };
             xmlhttp.open("GET","countryAction?country="+str,true);
              xmlhttp.send();
            }



           function onStateChange(str)

             {
           var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)

                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  alert(str);
               xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                 }
                     else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
               xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                 {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                     {
           document.getElementById("stateid").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
                };
                 xmlhttp.open("GET","stateAction?state="+str,true);
                  xmlhttp.send();
                }

          </script>
               <body>
         <table>
             <tr>
              <td>
         Select country name
                   </td>
            <td>
                   <select name="country" onchange="onCountryChange(this.value)">
                 <option value="">--choose--</option>
               <option value="india">india</option>
                    <option value="us">us</option>
                 </select>
               </td>
              </tr>

                 <tr>

              <td>
          Select State name
             </td>
                <td>
              <div id="conid">
                <select name="state" onchange="onStateChange(this.value)">
             <option value=" ">--choose</option>

            </select>
         </div>
        </td>
            </tr>

       <tr>
      <td>
       Select city name
            </td>
              <td>
              <div id="stateid">
              <select name="city">
            <option value=" ">--choose</option>
                 </select>
              </div>
                  </td>
                 </tr>


                </table>
                  </body>
                   </html>




                                        **state.jsp**



      <%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
     <%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
     <s:select list="statemap" name="state" headerKey="0" headerValue="select"   onchange="onStateChange(this.value)"></s:select>




                                          **city.jsp**





       <jsp:directive.page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
    <jsp:directive.taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s1"/>
    <s1:select list="citylist" name="city" headerKey="0" headerValue="select"/>





                                              **web.xml**




       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-  app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>DropdownCountrystatecity</display-name>
     <welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```